# What are the meanings of the DURATION string parts of RFC 5545?

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545, webcal

http://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-3-6-duration.html - this is the reference to the document. It is somewhat self explanatory, but still a little bit hard to grasp. Maybe someone could explain what does the `P` in `P15DT5H0M20S` stand for? Also, maybe there is some other code-character that can be substituted for the `P`. If so, what are the other characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the grammar, you might want to refer to the actual [RFC 5545 section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.6). Extract given below:

> 3.3.6.  Duration
> Value Name:  DURATION
>
> Purpose:  This value type is used to identify properties that contain
> a duration of time.

Format Definition:  This value type is defined by the following
notation:

> ```
>   dur-value  = (["+"] / "-") "P" (dur-date / dur-time / dur-week)
> ```

```
   dur-date   = dur-day [dur-time]
   dur-time   = "T" (dur-hour / dur-minute / dur-second)
   dur-week   = 1*DIGIT "W"
   dur-hour   = 1*DIGIT "H" [dur-minute]
   dur-minute = 1*DIGIT "M" [dur-second]
   dur-second = 1*DIGIT "S"
   dur-day    = 1*DIGIT "D"
```

from the standard, you can see that the letter `P` is an integral part of the grammar and that no other letter is considered.

Answer (score 2):

`P` is not subsitutable by anything - look at the grammar, it's the only not optional character, it stands for duration but the `D` was not available as it is used for days.

Comment: In [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), `P` stands for "Period". Since the `Duration` format in `RFC 5545` is a subset of ISO 8601 I would assume that it stands for Period there as well. Just nit-picking ;-)